# Debugging ASP.Net shared pool techniques

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-6, shared-hosting

I work for a hosting company, providing ASP.Net 3.5 hosting. Honestly, we usually provide quite good uptime and velocity. However, we are having problems with one of our shared pools. As usual, we try to maximize the number of webs that can run into one pool.

Lately we are suffering continuous hangs. The process doesn't crash, but starts to show OutOfMemoryExceptions or stops processing requests. We think this is responsability of one of the applications (it would be great to know which one).

I have some memory dumps that I have processed with WinDbg. I've run f.e:

```
!dumpheap -stat
```

This method provide global memory usage of objects. Nothing remarkable... Also I've checked:

```
~*e!clrstack
```

I see various non managed threads. In those who are managed appears stacks like:

```
[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0f30e320]            
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(System.Threading.WaitHandle...
0f30e3ec 7928b3ff System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(System.Threading...
0f30e40c 7a55fc89 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()...
0f30e45c 792d6e46 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System...
0f30e468 792f5781 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System...
```

At least, I haven't seen exception throwing or similar (in that moment). I've also had access to two scripts written by Tess Ferrandez for calculating the number of sessions and size. Also here not promising results. Anything peculiar or remarkable (24000 bytes as average).

I would like to know what kind of strategies are you usually using facing this kind of problems. Have you ever used Microsoft Support?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How many sites per pool are you running?

Comment: Would also be useful to know how much memory the server has and if its 32bit or 64bit windows2003.

Comment: Thanks Kev,

200 to 250 (little) websites on the same pool. First problems are appearing now. 4GB RAM, Windows 2003 32 Standard. As far as I know, the server has all the memory that he needs.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice question, well a bad asp.net can hang all shared web apps on the same pool...

Ok let see... if the problem is on memory, get the [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) from Sysinternals, and also the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Run them both, and from Process explorer find the **PID number** of pool that you wish to investigate, its under the inetinfo.exe, and have probably the name **aspnet_wp.exe**.

Now on the VMMap add for monitoring this Pool using for help the PID, and voila, you see the memory and the open images (aspx files) that probably are a lot and make the problems... The files that you going to see are located on temporary of asp.net Framework, but you can connect them and see from witch site they come from.

Well if the problem is not on memory, but the programmer have create bad loops, or even create thread sleeps, then I think process explorer is a way to investigate the pools and search for whats eating the power.

### Additional

Maybe a pool recycle every 15minute can solve this issue ?

### More about

In those videos there are a lot of informations about VMMap and memory manager.
[Mysteries of Windows Memory Management, Part 1](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1689962d-dea2-48bd-80d8-96e954fa5329), and [, Part 2](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/1c97b279-d7e3-4a3e-9a76-0dac23dfddb5)

Comment: Thanks Aristos,

Not promising results by now, but very interesting tools. I have used other times Process Monitor but it's a good idea in these cases. At least I've noticed how many resources are used to instantiate 'php-cgi.exe' in the shared pool.

Comment: Related to VMMap, the two largest amount of memory are for 'Private data'. I don't see suspicious DLL. As curiosity, and I know that probably this is not possible, it seems that hangs disappear when I'm watching with ProcessMonitor :)

I don't know if the lesson that we have to extract here is that we've put so many webs on the same pool and this is highly deprecated.

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks Aristos again ;)

Comment: @Jacob84 There is the case that some one is still developing his site and make some errors/bad programming, he finds it because page stack, and fix it, so thats why now all is ok.

Comment: @Jacob84 The how many pages you have place is depend from the memory/speed/trafic on the server and the kind of the pages. For example some very good sites need almost exclusive run, other dot net sites with only 2-10 pages and with out database, is like not exist. Why not break in 2-3 pools the sites (if you have memory). You do that from iis, and Plesk have nothing do with it. On my machine with 3Gb I have 4 pools, 2 is together for one app, the other 2 have the rest of sites break them in half (also we have Plesk)

Comment: @Jacob84 What you need to search for is dot net dll that actually is compiled pages, that have take a lot of memory or have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools, but it sounds like your main goal is to determine what's causing the problem. This can be done very simply with a binary search.

Break the pool in half, and see which one crashes. Repeat until you have a crashed pool with only one application in it.

This is already O(log2n), but you can speed the process up arbitrarily by dividing into more than two sub-pools.

Comment: Nice idea, but its better to combine it with at least some suspected sites. And to find the suspected sites he need some way to see whats happens on the system.

Comment: Thanks Steven and Aristos. Unfortunately, we're talking of 200 to 250 websites running in the same pool. Maybe we'll have to reconsider that. This must be combined with the fact of Paralells Plesk Control Panel and his permissions management.

So, we don't have suspects and we can't split (easily at least) the pool.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aristos: If there are some likely suspects, they could be moved out into a pool to see if it crashes. If yes, great, you saved time. If no, then it's back to binary searching. @Jacob84: Sorry to hear that. I'll continue thinking about this.